# GWT with superdevmode and external library

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm using GWT to make a webapp. I can use superdevmode, and I can use external libraries in production, but I seem to run into a problem when I combined the two. I am using this library for my oatuh2 login http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/ and I have

`<inherits name='com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.OAuth2' />`

in my Project.gwl.xml, and I have the .jar in my WEB-INF/lib folder. Everything works fine in production.

However, when I try to run it in superdevmode, I get

`[ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/api/gwt/oauth2/OAuth2.gwt.xml' on your classpath`.

If I don't use Oauth2, then superdevmode works fine. My program arguments in my run config is

`-src src\ -workDir "C:\My-Directory" -port 1234 com.package.Project`

Anyone have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Is the gwt-oauth2 JAR in the classpath when you launch SuperDevMode?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer that was it! Thanks. I'll answer my question after my requisite 8 hour wait is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT loads everything from the classpath (SuperDevMode also loads from the `-src` dirs), so if it can't find something, it generally means it's not in the classpath.